# Overload template function for generic enum and the other types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I have a generic function which works on any type of enum. I would like to overload it with custom defined classes as well as string and integer. But, I will receive a function overload error message. How can I fix that?

> error: call of overloaded 'show_value(MyAlpha)' is ambiguous

[wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CyTphNBBLHobZyJl)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum MyAlpha
{
   ALPHA,
   BETA
};

enum Animal
{
    ELEFANT,
    GOAT,
    RABIT
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    string text;
    MyClass(string text): text(text) {} 
};

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void show_value(T x) { cout<<"Enum: "<<(int)x<<endl; };

void show_value(int x) { cout<<"Int: "<<x<<endl; };

void show_value(string x) { cout<<"String: "<<x<<endl; };

template<class T>
void show_value(T x) { cout<<"Obj.text: "<<x.text<<endl; };


int main()
{
    show_value(MyAlpha(BETA));
    show_value(Animal(RABIT));
    show_value(5);
    show_value("Rainy day");
    show_value(MyClass("Waterfall"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using `enum class` instead raw `enum`

Comment: @NutCracker, I am glad to do that. The only problem is difficulty to serialize it.

Comment: Note that `show_value("Rainy day");` will not call the `string` overload but the generic one.

Comment: @Holt, You are correct. I need a cast to string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make the overloads of [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) *mutually exclusive*. Otherwise for `enum` types both the templated overloads are exact match.

e.g.

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void show_value(T x) { cout<<"Enum: "<<(int)x<<endl; };

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void show_value(T x) { cout<<"Obj.text: "<<x.text<<endl; };
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EbdSvCZXZdLUO88c)

---

<sup>PS: `"Rainy day"` is not of type `std::string` but `const char[]`. So change `show_value("Rainy day");` to `show_value(std::string("Rainy day"));`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void show_value(T x)
```

is not more specialized than (the catch all)

```
template<class T> void show_value(T x);
```

so calling with a `enum` is ambiguous.

You have either to discard the generic one for non enum:

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void show_value(T x) { std::cout << "Obj.text: " << x.text << std::endl; };
```

or giving them a priority.

```
struct low_priority_overload {};
struct high_priority_overload : low_priority_overload{};
// Or use template <std::size_t N> struct priority_overload : priority_overload<N - 1>{}

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void show_value_impl(high_priority_overload, T x) { cout<<"Enum: "<<(int)x<<endl; };

void show_value_impl(high_priority_overload, int x) { cout<<"Int: "<<x<<endl; };

void show_value_impl(high_priority_overload, string x) { cout<<"String: "<<x<<endl; };

template<class T>
void show_value_impl(low_priority_overload, T x) { cout<<"Obj.text: "<<x.text<<endl; };


template<class T>
void show_value(T x)
{
   show_value_impl(high_priority_overload{}, x);
}
```